# Typescript complains about duplicate const declarations inside different namespaces

Tags: typescript, babeljs

Why typescript is complaining about duplicate `const` declarations if they live inside different namespaces? Here is what I have:

```
export namespace Foo{
    export const ONE:string= 'foo one'
}
export namespace BAR{
    export const ONE:string= 'bar one'
}
```

And I get following typescript error:

```
Duplicate declaration "ONE"
```

I am using **typescript@3.1.6** and **@babel/preset-typescript**. As noted in comments namespaces are not supported with babel preset.But it doesnt work with modules also...
here is my babel config:

```
const presets = [
  '@babel/preset-react',
  ['@babel/env', {
    targets: {
      edge: '17',
      firefox: '60',
      chrome: '67',
      safari: '11.1',
    },
    useBuiltIns: 'usage',
    modules: 'commonjs',
  }],
  '@babel/preset-typescript',
]


module.exports = { presets }
```

Comment: Works in the playground .. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20namespace%20Foo%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20const%20ONE%3Astring%3D%20'foo%20one'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20namespace%20BAR%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20const%20ONE%3Astring%3D%20'bar%20one'%0D%0A%7D

Comment: I'm using 3.1.4 and can't reproduce it.

Comment: Don't use namespaces, they are deprecated in favor of modules.

Comment: Sorry, but one more important thing - Im using @babel/preset-typescript

Comment: Given that we know namespaces won't work, can you give the code you tried using modules that you expected to work?